# SQL Server Profiler takes forever with scalar function

Tags: sql-server, profiler, user-defined-functions

I wonder if anyone has had this problem before... I'm running SQL Server Profiler to gather performance info on a stored procedure on a very large database (millions of rows), and one statement uses a scalar UDF which essentially runs on all rows in the query. But with Profiler running, although I can tell it not to record function types, it still takes ages because it interrogates all calls (ie runs through the entire function for ever row). Is there any way to tell Profiler NOT to run through the body of a UDF?

Comment: Off topic but what does the scalar UDF do? If it is running against that many rows there may be better solutions. Examples: If it does data access then inlining it into a inline TVF can yield performance benefits. If it doesn't do data access it should be declared `WITH SCHEMABINDING`

Comment: Yes, changing it so that the UDF is not required is part of what I'm doing, but I want the ability to first record accurately how much time the individual procedure statements take, including the UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't completely clear (to me): Profiler doesn't run anything itself, it only 'observes' what's happening on the server. So you can tell Profiler "ignore events coming from the UDF", but you can't tell it "do not execute the UDF" because Profiler itself doesn't execute anything.

If you don't want the procedure to call the UDF, you need to comment it out or add conditional logic to not call the function when you pass a @NoUDF parameter or something similar. Although I'm not sure why you would want to comment it out anyway, because your performance analysis will presumably be less meaningful if you do?

Comment: Well, the issue is that when I run a SQL Trace, the statement takes forever (for example, I usually kill it after 18 hours). Whereas if I run the statement without a trace running, it takes 45 minutes. If I comment the UDF out of the query with Trace running, it takes about 35 minutes. All other conditions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a filter to exclude that `ObjectType` from the trace. The ObjectType to exclude [is `20038` I believe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180953.aspx).

Comment: That's what I have done. It prevents the trace from reporting the UDF, but it does not prevent the trace from reading it.

Comment: @tuseau - That's all you can do in SQL Trace. The trace filtering is applied after the event is routed to the subscriber. See [Internal Trace Components](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293610.aspx) If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can look into extended events which is architected differently.